# Проблема с установкой библиотеки pynput

Tags: python, pynput

Подскажите (ссылку) где можно скачать библиотеку "pynput скачать на Windows 11 бесплатно", просто ищу не могу скачать, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: не могу найти где скачать в поисковике? прописываю  скачать "pynput"  и ни где нет, где скачать??

Comment: А оно разве не через pip устанавливается?

Comment: в терминале? я не знаю, через "pip" я в PyCharm скачивал, но сейчас я в VS.

Comment: Точно так же через pip устанавливайте. И в Visual Studio и в vscode терминал есть. В общем, короткий ответ - устанавливаете с помощью `pip install pynput` как и практически любую другую библиотеку, никаких "скачать без регистрации и смс" гуглить даже не нужно.

Comment: а можете весь код написать правильно как надо написать?

Comment: я просто попробовал сам написать и мне ошибка выскочила "ERROR: unknown command "pynput"

Comment: благодарю, сейчас пошла скачиваться...магия прям какая-то))))))

Comment: @mark вот вам ссылка https://pypi.org/project/pynput/

Comment: "ERROR: unknown command "pynput" - значит вы писали `pip pynput` без `install`. Никакой магии, просто невнимательность.